# Inserting a character after the last set of numbers in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm interested in inserting a character (comma in this case ) after the last set of  numbers if they are present  in values of  a Pandas column. A sample of the original dataframe  is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID': ['1', '2', '3'], 'Address': ['123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont 0987', '123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont', '123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont 87']}
df_addresses = pd.DataFrame(data)`
```

Expected df output  is as below: -

```
data_expected = {'ID': ['1', '2', '3'], 'Address': ['123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont, 0987', '123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont', '123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont, 87']}
df_addresses_expected = pd.DataFrame(data_expected)
```

Ideally, a comma is  inserted  before the last set of  numbers in the  column value. If the last set of  characters is  not  a number-like value, the column is  left as it is. Any thoughts  around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to insert a comma into a string as you describe, and apply that function to the address column:

```py
def insert_comma(string):
    if string == '':
        return string
    if string[-1] not in '0123456789':
        return string
    words = string.split(' ')
    if len(words) <= 1:
        return string
    words[-2] += ','
    return ' '.join(words)

df_addresses['Address'] = df_addresses['Address'].apply(insert_comma)
df_addresses
```

```
    ID  Address
0   1   123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont, 0987
1   2   123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont
2   3   123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont, 87
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def check_for_final_comma(input_str):
    input_str_split = input_str.split(' ')
    last_word = input_str_split[-1]

    if last_word.isnumeric():
        if input_str_split[-2][-1] != ",":
            input_str_split[-2] += ","
            return " ".join(input_str_split)
    
    return input_str

df_addresses['Address_New'] = df_addresses['Address'].apply(check_for_final_comma)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using `apply` like this:

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.extract('(.+?)\s*(\d+)?$').fillna('').assign(t=', ')[[0, 't', 1]].sum(axis=1).str.strip(', ')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  ID                                            Address
0  1  123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont, 0987
1  2        123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont
2  3    123 Nelson Avenue, Redmont Central, Redmont, 87
```